# ayuda con input dinamicos en laravel 5.5

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".alergia-boton").click(function(){
  if($("#id_alergia_paciente").val().length <= 1){
    return false
  }
  else{
    let valor = $("#id_alergia_paciente").val();
    let html = $('#formulario_registro').html();

    html+=`<input type="text" name="alergia_paciente[]" value="${valor}">`;

    $('#formulario_registro').html(html);

    $('#id_alergia_paciente').val("");
  }
});});
```

> tengo este script q me genera input dinámicos y necesito guardarlos en una tabla q tiene campos id y alergias_paciente, los valúes de los input irían en alergias_paciente pero al guardarlos en el controlador con un for me agrega el id nada mas y me deja null el campo alergia_paciente es decir q no me esta recogiendo los datos de los input.

esta es la función que los guarda en el controlador :

```
DB::beginTransaction();
            try{

                    for($i=0;$i<=1;$i++){
                        $alergia = new Alergia;
                    $alergia->paciente_alergia_id = Auth::user()->id;
                    $alergia->alergia_paciente = $request->input('alergia_paciente['.$i.']');

                    $alergia->save();

                    }

            }catch(Exception $e){
            DB::rollback();      
            throw $e->getMessage();    
            return 'ERROR';

          }
          DB::commit();

          Sesion_usuario::Sesion_usuario();

          return 'EXITO';
```

podrían ayudarme a ver por que no me guarda los valúes de los input?

Comment: ¿qué datos son recibidos en el request?

Comment: serian los q el usuario ponga en los input q se generan con el script. estará mal la forma en q lo hago en el for?